# Edit needed on: Privileges - access review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

Sorry to hit on this so soon after roll out, but I found a minor error on the new privilege page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

This:

> The first queues you gain access to are Late Answers and First Posts.
>   These and all other review queues accessible from the "review" link
>   that appears at the top of every page next to your user name, though
>   you will only be able to perform reviews in the queues open to users
>   of your reputation level.

Should be this:

> The first queues you gain access to are Late Answers and First Posts.
>   These and all other review queues **are** accessible from the "review" link
>   that appears at the top of every page next to your user name, though
>   you will only be able to perform reviews in the queues open to users
>   of your reputation level.

Comment: Not sure if I've tagged this correctly, please advise...

Comment: Thanks for the re-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta has the proper text, though it may take a little while for it to propagate to all sites.